# Upgrade from Gazebo 7 to 7.1

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How can I upgrade from Gazebo 7.0 to 7.1? I am using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17397/upgrade-from-gazebo-7-to-7.1/) by [Ash_100](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3901/ash_100/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2017-10-04**:
It have to be 7.1? I think the latest version of gazebo7 is something around 7.8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Follow the alternative installation here:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=7.0

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ash_100](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3901/ash_100/) on 2017-10-06**:
I tried this. It upgrades to Gazebo7 not Gazebo7.1.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-10-06**:
Do you see 'packages.osrfoundation' with the command 'cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'? If you're getting from there, you should actually get the latest version, which is 7.8.1